# Changing code using MPMoviePlayerController to AVPlayer

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm taking an online course and they're using outdated code using MPMoviePlayerController, and I need specific instructions on what to change it to so that it works. The app I'm making has a table view controller with an inbox with messages in it. Short video files can be sent, and when you tap on a row that has a video message, I need the video file to play. The free trial is expiring soon, so I need help please.

This is what needs to be changed in my header file:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer;
```

This is what needs to be changed in my viewDidLoad method in my implementation file:

```
self.moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] init];
```

This is also what needs to be changed in the implementation file. I'm getting the videos through a backend via Parse.com, so that's what the PFFile is about:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    PFFile *videoFile = [self.selectedMessage objectForKey:@"file"];
    NSURL *fileUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:videoFile.url];
    self.moviePlayer.contentURL = fileUrl;
    [self.moviePlayer prepareToPlay];

    [self.view addSubview:self.moviePlayer.view];
    [self.moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Use this (https://github.com/piemonte/Player/) easy to use library which wraps AVPlayer.

Comment: I tried using the PBJVideoPlayer for my objective c project and plugged in the lines under the "Usage" section, but the "setup media" and the 3rd "present" lines are showing errors: Property 'videoPath' not found on object of type 'PBJVideoPlayerController' and No known class method for selector 'didMoveToParentViewController:' What can I do or change to make these lines work?

Answer (score 1):

In header file :

```
@property(nonatomic,strong)AVPlayer *avPlayer;
```

In viewDidLoad method in implementation file

```
self.avPlayer = [[AVPlayer alloc] init];
```

In implementation UITableView Method :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

     PFFile *videoFile = [self.selectedMessage objectForKey:@"file"];

    NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:videoFile.url];
    self.avPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:fileURL];

    AVPlayerLayer *layer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:self.avPlayer];
    self.avPlayer.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone;
    layer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height);
    [self.view.layer addSublayer: layer];

    [self.avPlayer play];

}
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: It's definitely better than before! Now when I tap on the video file row, the video plays right on the table view controller, below the row i tapped on, and above the navigation tab bar at the bottom. When the video ends, it just stays there and doesn't dismiss despite navigating away and back again. I added these 2 lines of code above the "layer.frame" line, because I was getting an error leaving "width" and "height" undefined.               >CGFloat width = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;            >CGFloat height = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;

Comment: Should those be defined differently? I'm hoping for the video to play on its own view full screen, like the player that you watch movies and stuff on.